# Can't insert into mysql database with mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a secret diary website for mysql practice. I've set up 4 columns to accept an id, email, password, and diary entry. The id is the primary key and auto increments whenever I use a query to insert the `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['password']`. I've successfully been able to add fake entries into the database so that isn't my issue. I'm following a video guide on how to do this and the instructor uses the method `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with the POST variable inside before inserting into the database and whenever I use it, only blank text is entered into my database. Whenever I don't use that method, my query writes to my db successfully. Can anyone explain why this is?

[image]

I've implemented checks prior to the following php code to add to my $error variable if the user doesn't fill in a field or enters incorrect email format.

```
if (!empty($error)) {
            $error = '<p><strong>There were error(s) in your sign-up:</strong></p>'.$error;
        } else {
                print_r($_POST);
                //$emailInput = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $emailInput = $_POST['email'];
                //$passwordInput = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
                $passwordInput = $_POST['password'];
                $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('$emailInput', '$passwordInput')";

                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                    echo "Sign Up Successful";
                } else {
                    $error .= "<p>Could not sign you up - please try again</p>";
                  }      
            }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires 2 arguments and you're only putting in one.

Comment: I don't like to guess, and I bet you don't either when troubleshooting ;-) So why don't you save us all the time, and implement proper error-reporting, both for PHP in general (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`) and for the query (`mysqli_error($link)`)?

Comment: don't go live with this; your db and users info are at stake

Comment: Use password hash.  Do not save plain text.  Your script mustn't go live.  It'll be hacked.Also on no account should you escape passwords. Don't!!

Comment: Uh.......@Akin?

Comment: I was missing the first parameter for mysqli_real_escape_string(), silly mistake. And I definitely don't plan on going live. This is my 2nd project using a db so this is just me getting the basics down. Password security is next on my list. Thank you for the feedback!